# UITableViewCell accessoryType doesn't work Xcode 6.0.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm testing a very simple app. I have a tableview with following code for setting up cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text=[phones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;

    return cell;
}
```

I used an UITableView in a UIViewController. I tried all types of accessoryType but nothing shows.
I tried to make another class that is a subclass of UITableViewController and it works fine (same source code as above).
Is it a bug in Xcode 6 or does Apple start to abandon Objective C?

UPDATE: [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/tableviewtesting) is the whole project.

Comment: I think the question is not here,the code you show.It should be some where else. Can you show more detail? May be the whole project.

Comment: Please check the project I've updated. Please use Xcode 6 to build

Comment: Can anyone give the answer? I think it's really simple question but I'm stuck for more than one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out the cause. I'm using autolayout and I'm not familiar with autolayout so I couldn't set it up properly (I guess). So I disabled autolayout (and size Classes) and adjust Auto Resizing for the tableview and it works fine for iPhone 4", 4.7" and 5.5".

Here is the illustration:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

YOu have to init your cell. For example:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I test your code but it's not true. I used storyboard for a long time and I didn't have to initialize the cell.

Comment: I also noticed that when I support "editting mode", the delete button doesn't show. With subclass of UITableViewController, it does show the delete button. How strange

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and my workaround is to set the accessory type in "viewDidAppear".

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UITableViewCell *c = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [c setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: it doesn't help, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Autolayout be sure to set the table view's margins